# In a React Native JavaScript app, why would the Android GC behavior change if I create a temporary variable, instead of returning a value directly?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, garbage-collection

I feel like there might be a bug somewhere in the Android GC, JavaScriptCore, or maybe Genymotion. I'm testing a React Native app on Android, so all of my code is written in JavaScript (not Java). I am trying to figure out a crash that I have reproduced on the following Android Emulators:

- Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 - API 23
- Google Nexus 5X - 7.1.0 - API 25

I noticed that my app was always crashing after I used it for around 5 minutes. After looking at the logs with `adb logcat`, I noticed that it was always crashing immediately after a GC run. It was only crashing on Android, and the crash has never happened on iOS. It was also only happening when "Debug JS Remotely" was turned off, and I just realized why. It's because when "Debug JS Remotely" is enabled, [all the JS is being run inside Chrome on my laptop, in the V8 engine](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-runtime). (Which made this quite hard to debug!)

I am using the [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library, but I'm using a branch with a configurable "cacheSize" to store multiple results, instead of just caching a single result. You can [see my new `defaultMemoize` function here](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/reselect/blob/6721a43efd84b1953aa83c0bb364435cd2e2ac70/src/index.js#L21-L88). My first thought is that I've done something wrong in here, but I'm not using a `WeakMap` or something like that. I'm just storing the cached results in a normal array, and I'm always holding a reference to the selector, so I don't think the GC should be clearing the memory.

I'll describe some more details about my app. I have a `LookupTable` class, which references a `Matrix` class. The lookup table pre-calculates some things for faster lookups.

My lookup table code looks something like this:

```
// @flow
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator'

export default class LookupTable {
  matrix: Matrix

  constructor(state) {
    this.generateLookupTable(state)
  }

  @autobind
  valueAt(x: number, y: number) {
    this.matrix.get(x, y)
  }

  @autobind
  generateLookupTable() {
    // generates the Matrix at this.matrix
  }
}
```

My original selector code looked like this:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import { createSelectorCreator, defaultMemoize } from 'reselect'

const createImmutableSelector = (cacheSize = 1, ...args) =>
  createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, Immutable.is, cacheSize)(...args)

export const lookupTableSelector = createImmutableSelector(3,
  firstSelector,
  secondSelector,
  thirdSelector,
  fourthSelector,
  (one, two, three, four) =>
    new LookupTable(one, two, three, four))
```

If you're not familiar with `reselect` or `immutable-js`, I'm just memoizing some calculations (similar to lodash's `memoize`), and I'm using `Immutable.is` to check argument equality.

Finally, I would call the selector like this:

```
const lookupTable = lookupTableSelector(state)
const value = lookupTable.valueAt(x, y)
```

After the Android GC runs, `valueAt` was causing a crash, because `this.matrix` was undefined. Interestingly, the `lookupTable.generateLookupTable` function was also undefined. In fact, everything in the instance was undefined. It's like the selector was just returning a shell of a `LookupTable` instance, where all of the data and methods were gone.

So here is my attempt at a workaround:

```
export const lookupTableSelectorWithoutGCFix = createImmutableSelector(3,
  firstSelector,
  secondSelector,
  thirdSelector,
  fourthSelector,
  (one, two, three, four) =>
    new LookupTable(one, two, three, four))


export const lookupTableSelector = (gameState: Map) => {
  const lookupTable = lookupTableSelectorWithoutGCFix(gameState)

  if (lookupTable.matrix == null) {
    console.warn('LookupTable selector returned an instance with an undefined matrix.' +
      'This might be a GC bug on Android. Will clear the cache and generate a new instance.')
    lookupTableSelectorWithoutGCFix.clearCache()
    return lookupTableSelectorWithoutGCFix(gameState)
  }

  return lookupTable
}
```

Now the weird thing is that this code is never actually called. I never see the console warning in `adb logcat`, and it never shows up as a yellow box in the emulator. Before this, the crash was happening after every GC run. But after this change, I tested the app through 5 GC runs, and everything just worked perfectly. So whatever I did here, I guess it changed the behavior of the Android GC, and it's no longer wiping out the memory for my `LookupTable` instances.

Can you see a reason why this would be happening? Or is this probably a reference counting bug in the Android GC?